# Web scraping shot range data of NBA players in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to export the shooting range [data](https://stats.nba.com/players/shooting/?Season=2002-03&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&sort=25-29%20ft.%20FGA&dir=1). I just got exposed to python. My code is as follows:

```
from selenium 
import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path_to_chromedriver = "D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
url='https://stats.nba.com/players/shooting/?Season=2002-03&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&sort=25-29%20ft.%20FGA&dir=1'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/label').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/nba-stat-table/div[3]').click()
table = browser.find_element_by_class_name('nba-stat-table__overflow')
df=[]  
for line_id, lines in enumerate(table.text.split('\n')):  
    if line_id == 0: 
        column_names = lines.split(' ')[1:] 
    else:
        DFS.append(lines)
```

For sure I failed to get my answers. That's the reason I come to this platform to ask for your kind help. What I want to get is the data of total 9 pages (428 rows) of that html.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

the_select = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="stats-table-pagination__inner stats-table-pagination__inner--top"]//select')))
the_select.click()
the_select.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@label="All"]').click()
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'nba-stat-table__overflow')))

for line_id, lines in enumerate(table.text.split('\n')):
    # print(line_id, lines)

    if line_id == 0: 
        column_names = lines.split(' ')[1:] 
    else:
        df.append(lines)

print(df)
```

output:

> ['LESS THAN 5FT. 5-9 FT. 10-14 FT. 15-19 FT. 20-24 FT. 25-29 FT.', '', '', '', '', 'PLAYER TEAM AGE FGM FGA FG% FGM FGA FG% FGM FGA FG% FGM FGA FG% FGM FGA FG% FGM FGA FG%', 'A.J. Guyton', 'GSW 25 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 - - -', 'Aaron McKie', 'PHI 30 1.6 2.7 57.1 0.3 0.8 35.0 0.3 1.1 30.0 0.8 1.9 40.0 0.6 1.4 41.2 0.1 0.4 20.7', 'Aaron Williams', 'NJN 31 1.5 2.8 52.6 0.5 1.3 40.2 0.2 0.6 36.2 0.2 0.7 35.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Adam Harrington', 'DEN 22 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.5 50.0 0.3 0.9 26.7 0.3 0.9 33.3', 'Adonal Foyle', 'GSW 28 1.5 2.6 58.8 0.4 1.0 44.9 0.2 0.4 54.3 0.1 0.2 31.6 0.0 0.0 100 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Adrian Griffin', 'DAL 28 0.6 1.0 54.7 0.3 0.7 46.2 0.2 0.5 28.9 0.7 1.5 48.1 0.2 0.8 30.0 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Al Harrington', 'IND 23 2.0 3.8 51.9 0.3 1.0 27.8 1.0 2.5 39.2 1.2 2.7 44.8 0.3 0.7 38.2 0.1 0.2 27.8', 'Alan Henderson', 'ATL 30 1.2 1.9 64.2 0.2 0.8 26.1 0.2 0.6 32.6 0.2 0.6 36.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Allan Houston', 'NYK 32 0.5 1.3 37.3 0.7 1.3 50.9 1.5 3.0 49.0 2.3 5.1 44.8 2.3 5.1 45.1 0.7 1.9 36.7', 'Allen Iverson', 'PHI 28 3.7 7.0 53.6 0.5 1.5 34.7 0.9 2.8 33.0 2.7 6.8 40.1 1.3 3.3 39.0 0.6 2.3 27.3', 'Alton Ford', 'PHX 22 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.5 0.8 66.7 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Alvin Williams', 'TOR 28 1.0 1.9 53.0 0.5 1.2 38.1 0.6 1.3 47.6 1.4 3.3 40.8 1.3 2.8 46.8 0.3 1.0 29.7', 'Amal McCaskill', 'ATL 29 0.4 1.5 25.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', "Amar'e Stoudemire", 'PHX 20 3.6 6.3 57.3 0.9 2.5 33.5 0.2 0.7 23.0 0.1 0.3 28.6 0.0 0.1 16.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Andre Miller', 'LAC 27 1.7 3.3 51.3 0.9 2.1 41.9 0.9 2.3 37.6 0.9 2.2 38.9 0.2 0.7 27.1 0.2 0.7 27.6', 'Andrei Kirilenko', 'UTA 22 2.7 4.0 67.7 0.0 0.3 9.5 0.1 0.5 21.6 0.4 1.3 31.1 0.5 1.5 33.1 0.2 0.4 43.8', 'Andrew DeClercq', 'ORL 30 1.7 2.9 58.6 0.2 0.5 40.0 0.1 0.2 26.7 0.0 0.1 22.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Anfernee Hardaway', 'PHX 31 1.3 2.3 57.0 0.4 1.0 35.0 0.6 1.3 43.2 1.4 3.0 45.9 0.7 2.0 36.8 0.1 0.3 27.8', 'Ansu Sesay', 'SEA 26 0.6 1.1 52.1 0.1 0.2 25.0 0.0 0.1 20.0 0.3 0.9 31.6 0.0 0.2 12.5 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Antawn Jamison', 'GSW 27 3.0 4.5 66.8 1.9 4.0 46.8 0.8 2.0 39.6 1.3 3.4 37.2 1.2 3.1 39.1 0.3 0.9 31.5', 'Anthony Carter', 'MIA 28 0.7 1.2 53.3 0.1 0.3 41.7 0.1 0.4 41.2 0.7 2.2 30.8 0.1 0.6 20.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Anthony Goldwire', 'WAS 31 0.1 0.3 40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.7 37.5 0.3 0.7 50.0 0.0 0.3 0.0', 'Anthony Johnson', 'NJN 28 0.6 0.9 61.3 0.2 0.4 48.1 0.2 0.5 41.4 0.4 1.0 33.8 0.2 0.5 36.4 0.1 0.3 41.7', 'Anthony Mason', 'MIL 36 1.5 2.6 56.2 0.5 1.1 46.6 0.6 1.7 35.8 0.4 0.6 56.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Anthony Peeler', 'MIN 33 0.6 1.0 56.0 0.0 0.2 15.8 0.1 0.5 31.6 0.8 2.0 39.5 1.0 2.5 42.6 0.5 1.3 38.8', 'Antoine Rigaudeau', 'DAL 31 0.4 0.7 50.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.2 1.0 18.2 0.2 1.1 18.2 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Antoine Walker', 'BOS 26 3.2 6.4 50.3 1.3 3.4 37.2 0.5 1.6 30.7 0.2 0.8 28.3 1.1 3.6 29.5 1.4 4.0 35.6', 'Antonio Daniels', 'POR 28 0.6 0.9 61.7 0.2 0.3 66.7 0.1 0.3 41.2 0.1 0.4 28.0 0.3 0.8 37.0 0.1 0.3 23.1', 'Antonio Davis', 'TOR 34 2.0 4.1 49.5 0.7 1.8 40.9 1.1 2.6 40.7 1.0 3.4 30.2 0.1 0.2 37.5 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Antonio Harvey', 'ATL 32 0.5 0.5 100 0.0 0.8 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Art Long', 'TOR 30 0.6 1.3 47.1 0.1 0.7 20.0 0.2 0.3 50.0 0.1 0.6 21.4 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Arvydas Sabonis', 'POR 38 1.2 2.2 54.7 0.4 1.0 40.7 0.1 0.3 36.8 0.2 0.6 38.3 0.3 0.5 48.8 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Austin Croshere', 'IND 28 0.6 1.2 53.4 0.1 0.1 60.0 0.2 0.4 36.8 0.2 0.9 23.8 0.5 1.1 41.2 0.3 0.8 41.2', 'Avery Johnson', 'DAL 38 0.8 1.7 46.3 0.2 0.5 35.0 0.1 0.3 41.7 0.3 0.7 40.0 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Baron Davis', 'NOH 24 2.7 5.0 54.8 0.3 1.0 29.2 0.6 1.5 39.5 0.6 2.0 32.3 1.4 3.7 36.8 1.0 2.8 36.8', 'Ben Wallace', 'DET 28 2.4 4.0 58.7 0.1 0.5 27.3 0.1 0.5 27.0 0.2 0.9 27.0 0.0 0.1 14.3 0.0 0.0 33.3', 'Bimbo Coles', 'BOS 35 0.2 0.6 33.3 0.1 0.2 25.0 0.3 0.9 30.0 0.7 1.9 36.4 0.3 0.9 38.7 0.1 0.2 25.0', 'Bo Outlaw', 'PHX 32 1.6 2.7 61.3 0.2 0.4 43.3 0.0 0.2 25.0 0.1 0.2 27.8 0.0 0.1 40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Bob Sura', 'GSW 30 1.6 2.9 54.1 0.2 0.6 28.1 0.0 0.2 16.7 0.1 0.5 18.5 0.4 0.9 40.4 0.2 0.9 26.1', 'Bobby Jackson', 'SAC 30 2.4 3.8 63.5 0.2 0.6 35.1 0.3 0.7 42.5 0.8 2.1 38.1 1.7 4.2 41.3 0.3 0.9 36.5', 'Bobby Simmons', 'WAS 23 0.4 0.9 42.4 0.1 0.3 25.0 0.0 0.2 25.0 0.6 1.6 39.6 0.3 0.6 47.1 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Bonzi Wells', 'POR 26 3.0 4.9 60.7 0.3 1.0 32.4 0.5 1.4 35.0 1.0 3.0 34.1 0.9 2.5 36.8 0.1 0.4 26.1', 'Bostjan Nachbar', 'HOU 22 0.4 0.6 66.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.2 0.4 60.0 0.1 1.0 7.7 0.1 0.2 50.0', 'Brad Miller', 'IND 27 2.6 4.2 60.5 0.2 0.8 28.3 0.5 1.2 42.9 0.9 2.2 42.9 0.2 0.5 36.8 0.0 0.1 37.5', 'Brandon Armstrong', 'NJN 23 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.3 0.7 40.0 0.2 0.7 33.3 0.0 0.3 0.0', 'Brandon Williams', 'ATL 28 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.2 0.6 33.3 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Brendan Haywood', 'WAS 23 1.7 2.8 61.3 0.1 0.6 21.6 0.2 0.6 39.1 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Brent Barry', 'SEA 31 1.4 2.2 63.4 0.2 0.4 41.9 0.0 0.1 20.0 0.1 0.5 30.6 1.0 2.2 43.9 0.8 2.3 35.3', 'Brevin Knight', 'MEM 27 0.5 1.0 51.9 0.1 0.4 36.4 0.1 0.3 20.0 0.7 1.7 42.7 0.3 0.6 42.9 0.0 0.0 50.0', 'Brian Cardinal', 'WAS 26 0.2 0.2 100 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0', 'Brian Grant', 'MIA 31 2.1 3.3 62.8 0.3 0.8 43.1 0.4 1.1 40.0 1.2 2.8 43.5 0.1 0.2 46.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Brian Scalabrine', 'NJN 25 0.4 0.9 46.3 0.1 0.3 42.9 0.0 0.2 28.6 0.3 0.7 39.5 0.2 0.8 28.6 0.2 0.4 57.1', 'Brian Shaw', 'LAL 37 0.2 0.4 54.8 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.1 0.3 25.0 0.3 0.7 46.9 0.3 1.0 31.9 0.4 1.0 44.8', 'Brian Skinner', 'PHI 27 1.9 2.9 64.2 0.3 0.9 36.6 0.1 0.4 31.0 0.0 0.1 40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Bruce Bowen', 'SAS 32 0.8 1.2 63.7 0.1 0.5 28.2 0.2 0.4 44.8 0.3 0.7 37.3 1.3 2.8 46.1 0.1 0.2 29.4', 'Bruno Sundov', 'BOS 23 0.3 0.5 57.1 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.7 15.4 0.1 0.5 20.0 0.1 0.4 28.6', 'Bryce Drew', 'NOH 28 0.1 0.2 33.3 0.1 0.1 100 0.1 0.4 20.0 0.2 0.8 18.2 0.2 0.4 40.0 0.1 0.3 50.0', 'Bryon Russell', 'WAS 32 0.3 0.7 46.2 0.0 0.1 20.0 0.1 0.2 33.3 0.3 0.7 36.7 0.7 1.9 36.4 0.2 0.9 24.1', 'Calbert Cheaney', 'UTA 31 1.5 2.2 65.9 0.2 0.6 40.8 0.4 0.8 45.6 1.2 2.8 43.9 0.7 1.5 45.3 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Calvin Booth', 'SEA 27 0.5 1.0 55.6 0.2 0.3 50.0 0.2 0.3 60.0 0.2 0.7 30.3 0.0 0.2 9.1 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Carlos Arroyo', 'UTA 23 0.5 0.8 62.2 0.2 0.5 35.7 0.2 0.4 50.0 0.4 0.9 39.4 0.1 0.3 18.2 0.1 0.1 66.7', 'Carlos Boozer', 'CLE 21 2.7 4.4 61.6 0.3 0.7 40.4 0.4 0.9 45.7 0.7 1.7 43.0 0.0 0.1 28.6 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Caron Butler', 'MIA 23 2.8 5.1 53.9 0.5 1.5 33.6 0.5 1.6 32.0 0.9 2.6 33.2 0.7 1.8 38.6 0.2 0.4 39.4', 'Casey Jacobsen', 'PHX 22 0.7 1.4 49.5 0.0 0.1 12.5 0.1 0.2 54.5 0.1 0.4 24.1 0.8 2.0 38.2 0.1 0.7 16.7', 'Cezary Trybanski', 'MEM 23 0.3 0.6 44.4 0.1 0.5 16.7 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Charles Oakley', 'WAS 39 0.1 0.3 46.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100 0.3 0.8 38.2 0.0 0.1 40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Charles Smith', 'POR 27 0.3 0.3 100 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 - - -', 'Charlie Ward', 'NYK 32 0.5 0.9 55.7 0.1 0.2 46.7 0.0 0.2 21.4 0.2 0.4 41.4 0.9 2.4 36.9 0.8 2.0 39.4', 'Chauncey Billups', 'DET 26 1.2 2.6 48.1 0.2 0.4 41.9 0.4 0.9 48.5 0.6 1.7 35.7 1.4 3.0 46.8 1.1 3.1 35.0', 'Cherokee Parks', 'LAC 30 1.4 2.2 63.1 0.3 0.4 90.0 0.1 0.5 21.4 0.8 2.0 36.8 0.3 0.6 47.1 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Chris Andersen', 'DEN 24 1.5 2.9 52.0 0.1 0.5 25.0 0.1 0.5 21.7 0.2 0.8 20.4 0.0 0.1 12.5 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Chris Childs', 'NJN 35 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.4 0.7 50.0 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Chris Crawford', 'ATL 28 0.4 0.6 66.7 0.2 0.2 100 0.4 0.6 66.7 0.4 0.6 66.7 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.3 0.5 50.0', 'Chris Dudley', 'POR 38 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Chris Jefferies', 'TOR 23 0.4 0.9 45.8 0.0 0.3 14.3 0.0 0.1 40.0 0.4 1.1 33.3 0.6 1.1 49.1 0.1 0.6 25.0', 'Chris Mihm', 'CLE 23 1.3 2.5 50.0 0.3 0.9 37.0 0.2 0.7 28.6 0.4 1.3 31.9 0.0 0.1 33.3 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Chris Mills', 'GSW 33 0.4 1.0 42.9 0.2 0.5 33.3 0.1 0.3 28.6 0.8 1.9 40.0 0.3 0.8 33.3 0.2 0.8 28.6', 'Chris Owens', 'MEM 24 1.0 2.0 50.0 - - - 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 100 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Chris Webber', 'SAC 30 3.6 5.9 60.3 1.6 4.0 39.4 0.7 1.8 36.9 3.3 7.5 44.0 0.7 1.9 37.5 0.0 0.2 15.4', 'Chris Whitney', 'ORL 31 0.2 0.3 62.5 0.1 0.3 23.1 0.1 0.5 28.0 0.5 1.5 33.3 1.1 2.7 42.2 0.5 1.8 27.3', 'Chris Wilcox', 'LAC 20 1.1 1.8 64.2 0.4 0.9 39.5 0.2 0.4 35.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Christian Laettner', 'WAS 33 1.1 1.9 60.8 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.4 0.7 51.9 1.5 3.1 49.6 0.2 0.6 35.6 0.0 0.1 14.3', 'Chucky Atkins', 'DET 28 0.6 1.2 45.0 0.1 0.3 20.0 0.0 0.2 16.7 0.5 1.3 36.6 0.8 2.1 36.0 0.7 1.9 37.4', 'Clar. Weatherspoon', 'NYK 32 1.6 3.2 49.0 0.2 0.6 34.0 0.3 0.7 37.9 0.3 0.7 41.8 0.0 0.0 66.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Clifford Robinson', 'DET 36 1.2 2.3 52.5 0.9 1.9 47.1 0.5 1.5 32.2 0.9 2.3 36.8 0.4 1.4 31.6 0.7 2.1 34.3', 'Corey Benjamin', 'ATL 25 1.0 2.0 50.0 0.1 0.7 16.7 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.1 1.2 9.1 0.1 0.4 33.3', 'Corey Maggette', 'LAC 23 2.7 4.3 61.2 0.2 0.7 35.7 0.1 0.5 26.7 0.7 2.0 33.8 1.1 3.1 35.7 0.6 1.5 37.9', 'Corie Blount', 'CHI 34 0.5 0.9 51.1 0.0 0.3 16.7 0.3 0.7 40.0 0.5 0.9 59.1 0.0 0.1 66.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Corliss Williamson', 'DET 29 2.7 4.7 56.6 1.1 2.4 44.0 0.4 1.5 30.3 0.3 1.3 26.2 0.1 0.2 33.3 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Courtney Alexander', 'NOH 26 0.9 2.0 47.3 0.1 0.3 31.6 0.5 1.2 39.5 0.8 2.6 32.5 0.5 1.3 40.7 0.1 0.4 20.0', 'Cuttino Mobley', 'HOU 27 2.5 4.2 58.1 0.3 0.9 36.8 0.5 1.2 39.8 1.0 2.4 41.6 1.4 3.8 37.4 0.6 1.9 32.6', 'Dajuan Wagner', 'CLE 20 2.1 4.6 44.9 0.7 2.1 34.3 0.4 1.1 34.0 0.2 0.9 26.2 0.8 2.4 32.4 0.6 1.8 32.5', 'Dale Davis', 'POR 34 2.2 3.3 65.5 0.2 0.7 27.8 0.4 1.0 39.5 0.3 0.6 47.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Dalibor Bagaric', 'CHI 22 0.2 0.6 33.3 0.2 1.0 22.2 0.2 0.8 28.6 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.1 0.1 100 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Damon Jones', 'SAC 26 0.3 0.5 54.2 0.1 0.1 57.1 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.2 0.5 30.8 0.8 2.0 38.5 0.3 1.1 28.6', 'Damon Stoudamire', 'POR 29 0.6 1.4 47.5 0.2 0.7 30.8 0.1 0.5 29.6 0.5 1.4 38.3 0.9 2.6 36.8 0.2 0.7 32.4', 'Damone Brown', 'TOR 24 0.8 1.4 57.1 0.2 0.8 25.0 0.5 1.8 28.6 0.6 2.6 23.1 0.2 0.6 33.3 0.0 0.2 0.0', 'Dan Dickau', 'ATL 24 0.4 0.8 51.2 0.1 0.5 23.8 0.0 0.2 22.2 0.3 0.6 50.0 0.4 1.0 43.2 0.3 0.8 34.5', 'Dan Gadzuric', 'MIL 25 1.1 1.8 60.0 0.2 0.7 22.6 0.1 0.3 46.7 0.0 0.2 25.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Dan Langhi', 'PHX 25 0.2 0.5 45.2 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.1 0.3 29.4 0.7 1.6 43.7 0.4 1.0 38.9 0.0 0.2 22.2', 'Danny Ferry', 'SAS 36 0.1 0.1 66.7 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.1 0.3 46.7 0.1 0.5 25.9 0.3 0.9 37.0 0.1 0.4 27.8', 'Danny Fortson', 'GSW 27 0.6 1.3 50.0 0.2 0.9 25.0 0.1 0.3 50.0 0.2 0.7 30.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Danny Manning', 'DET 37 0.5 0.8 63.6 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.3 0.7 37.5 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.2 0.4 50.0', 'Darius Miles', 'CLE 21 2.5 4.3 57.7 0.3 1.3 25.9 0.3 1.1 29.2 0.7 2.4 28.0 0.1 0.4 28.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Darrell Armstrong', 'ORL 35 0.9 1.6 53.7 0.0 0.3 19.0 0.2 0.5 39.5 0.8 2.0 41.7 0.9 2.4 38.1 0.4 1.0 35.3', 'Darvin Ham', 'ATL 29 0.7 1.4 51.0 0.0 0.1 42.9 0.0 0.2 27.3 0.2 0.5 37.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'David Robinson', 'SAS 37 2.3 4.2 55.0 0.2 0.6 35.0 0.2 0.8 27.8 0.3 0.8 35.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'David Wesley', 'NOH 32 1.2 2.2 53.7 0.2 0.5 44.1 0.2 0.6 38.3 1.6 4.2 38.9 2.5 5.5 45.2 0.4 1.3 34.1', 'DeSagana Diop', 'CLE 21 0.4 0.9 43.5 0.1 0.3 17.4 0.1 0.4 30.3 0.1 0.3 37.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'DeShawn Stevenson', 'UTA 22 0.7 1.4 46.5 0.0 0.3 16.7 0.2 0.5 39.1 0.7 1.8 38.6 0.4 1.1 38.3 0.0 0.1 50.0', 'Dean Oliver', 'GSW 24 0.2 0.7 30.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.1 0.5 16.7 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.1 0.4 25.0', 'Derek Anderson', 'POR 28 1.4 2.3 63.7 0.2 0.4 52.9 0.3 0.7 38.0 0.8 2.2 36.4 1.6 4.2 38.9 0.4 1.4 29.5', 'Derek Fisher', 'LAL 28 0.6 1.3 49.1 0.2 0.3 52.0 0.3 0.8 38.7 1.3 2.8 47.4 1.5 3.4 42.6 0.3 0.8 30.9', 'Derrick Coleman', 'PHI 36 1.9 3.3 57.9 0.4 1.0 35.9 0.4 1.3 30.9 0.4 0.9 38.3 0.3 0.6 41.5 0.2 0.7 32.6', 'Desmond Mason', 'MIL 25 2.1 3.6 60.2 0.3 1.0 31.7 0.5 1.2 39.6 1.5 3.6 40.5 1.2 2.9 42.6 0.1 0.4 19.4', 'Devean George', 'LAL 25 0.9 1.6 58.0 0.1 0.5 22.9 0.2 0.5 31.4 0.5 1.5 33.9 0.5 1.6 33.3 0.3 0.8 38.9', 'Devin Brown', 'DEN 24 0.6 1.1 54.5 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.1 0.3 50.0 0.4 1.6 28.6 0.1 0.6 20.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Dikembe Mutombo', 'NJN 37 1.2 2.9 42.0 0.6 1.9 32.6 0.3 0.5 46.2 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Dion Glover', 'ATL 24 1.7 3.3 50.8 0.1 0.4 22.2 0.3 0.7 41.2 0.7 1.8 39.6 0.6 1.4 43.5 0.3 1.0 30.3', 'Dirk Nowitzki', 'DAL 25 2.3 3.5 65.0 0.4 1.0 38.8 1.4 2.8 50.9 2.1 5.1 40.3 2.0 4.7 42.9 0.5 1.6 32.5', 'Don Reid', 'DET 29 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Donnell Harvey', 'DEN 22 2.1 3.9 54.0 0.5 1.5 33.0 0.2 0.5 43.2 0.4 1.1 32.1 0.1 0.2 26.7 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Donny Marshall', 'NJN 30 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - - - 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.0 - - -', 'Donyell Marshall', 'CHI 30 3.4 6.1 55.9 0.7 2.0 35.7 0.2 0.9 24.6 0.4 1.1 39.3 0.5 1.2 38.1 0.1 0.4 30.0', 'Doug Christie', 'SAC 33 1.5 2.2 66.5 0.1 0.2 46.2 0.1 0.3 34.8 0.3 1.1 28.2 1.1 2.5 46.2 0.2 0.7 33.9', 'Drew Gooden', 'ORL 21 2.1 3.8 55.3 1.1 2.5 41.8 0.7 1.6 43.4 0.8 1.9 39.6 0.4 0.8 42.4 0.1 0.4 25.0', 'Earl Boykins', 'GSW 27 0.6 1.1 53.3 0.5 1.1 43.4 0.7 1.3 49.4 0.7 1.9 34.1 0.4 0.9 45.8 0.2 0.5 32.4', 'Earl Watson', 'MEM 24 0.7 1.3 54.8 0.3 0.7 43.4 0.2 0.5 40.5 0.4 0.9 44.4 0.4 1.0 36.3 0.2 0.5 37.8', 'Eddie Griffin', 'HOU 21 1.1 1.8 61.2 0.5 1.3 42.3 0.5 1.3 38.2 0.4 1.6 26.2 0.4 1.2 34.7 0.6 1.7 33.3', 'Eddie House', 'MIA 25 0.5 0.7 63.4 0.1 0.3 41.2 0.3 0.9 33.3 1.2 2.8 43.3 0.9 2.9 32.0 0.2 0.7 30.0', 'Eddie Jones', 'MIA 31 1.6 3.2 48.7 0.4 1.0 38.3 0.7 1.5 46.5 1.1 2.9 36.2 2.0 4.7 42.8 0.5 1.2 38.2', 'Eddie Robinson', 'CHI 27 1.2 1.9 66.4 0.2 0.5 40.6 0.4 0.8 44.4 0.4 1.3 32.9 0.2 0.3 57.9 0.0 0.1 0.0', 'Eddy Curry', 'CHI 20 3.0 4.5 67.0 0.9 1.9 48.3 0.2 0.6 35.4 0.0 0.2 28.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Eduardo Najera', 'DAL 26 2.0 3.1 66.0 0.2 0.4 47.6 0.1 0.3 31.3 0.3 0.8 33.3 0.1 0.1 57.1 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Efthimios Rentzias', 'PHI 27 0.2 0.4 40.0 0.2 0.3 60.0 0.0 0.3 14.3 0.2 0.7 22.7 0.1 0.1 66.7 0.1 0.3 50.0', 'Elden Campbell', 'SEA 34 0.8 1.8 45.5 0.4 1.1 35.5 0.4 1.0 34.5 0.5 1.3 40.0 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Elton Brand', 'LAC 24 4.3 6.7 63.9 1.4 3.6 39.5 1.0 2.6 38.4 0.5 1.5 36.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Emanual Davis', 'ATL 34 0.4 0.8 47.4 0.0 0.2 20.0 0.1 0.2 40.0 0.5 1.0 52.2 0.3 1.1 25.9 0.0 0.3 14.3', 'Eric Piatkowski', 'LAC 32 1.3 2.0 65.9 0.1 0.3 26.3 0.2 0.6 44.1 0.3 0.7 41.3 0.7 1.7 40.2 0.8 2.0 40.5', 'Eric Snow', 'PHI 30 1.9 3.5 54.9 0.2 0.7 34.5 0.9 2.2 38.5 1.2 2.7 44.4 0.1 0.3 40.7 0.1 0.2 25.0', 'Eric Williams', 'BOS 30 1.7 3.0 55.8 0.5 1.3 39.8 0.2 0.8 28.6 0.2 0.5 35.7 0.4 1.2 35.6 0.1 0.2 33.3', 'Erick Dampier', 'GSW 27 2.5 4.1 59.4 0.5 1.6 31.3 0.1 0.4 33.3 0.1 0.2 31.3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Erick Strickland', 'IND 29 0.7 1.2 58.1 0.0 0.2 13.3 0.2 0.5 37.1 0.4 1.0 43.9 0.4 1.3 35.2 0.6 1.3 43.7', 'Ervin Johnson', 'MIL 35 0.6 1.3 50.6 0.1 0.3 45.5 0.1 0.3 30.0 0.0 0.1 16.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Etan Thomas', 'WAS 25 1.2 2.0 57.9 0.3 0.9 30.3 0.2 0.4 46.2 0.0 0.1 50.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Evan Eschmeyer', 'DAL 28 0.2 0.6 36.4 0.1 0.3 50.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.1 100 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Flip Murray', 'SEA 23 0.6 1.1 53.3 0.1 0.4 33.3 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.1 0.4 25.0 0.0 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0', 'Frank Williams', 'NYK 23 0.0 0.4 12.5 0.1 0.3 20.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.8 46.7 0.0 0.2 0.0', 'Fred Hoiberg', 'CHI 30 0.3 0.5 58.1 0.0 0.1 33.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.2 0.5 33.3 0.3 0.7 35.7 0.1 0.2 27.3', 'Fred Jones', 'IND 24 0.3 0.6 45.5 0.1 0.1 100 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.1 0.4 20.0 0.1 0.3 25.0', 'Gary Payton', 'MIL 34 4.2 6.8 60.9 0.7 2.0 33.1 0.9 2.3 40.0 1.5 4.0 37.5 0.8 2.2 37.3 0.2 0.9 26.4', 'Gary Trent', 'MIN 28 1.4 1.9 75.5 0.6 1.3 46.5 0.3 0.7 42.9 0.3 1.0 31.6 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'George Lynch', 'NOH 32 0.9 1.8 49.0 0.1 0.3 33.3 0.1 0.4 28.6 0.3 0.7 37.9 0.4 1.1 38.1 0.0 0.2 27.3', 'Gerald Wallace', 'SAC 20 1.6 2.4 64.6 0.0 0.2 20.0 0.0 0.1 25.0 0.2 0.8 21.6 0.1 0.4 35.3 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Gilbert Arenas', 'GSW 21 2.8 5.0 56.1 0.2 0.7 23.7 0.4 1.0 41.3 1.0 2.6 38.0 1.0 2.9 36.4 0.8 2.1 36.2', 'Glen Rice', 'HOU 36 0.4 0.8 51.0 0.2 0.6 41.7 0.2 0.5 43.8 0.3 0.6 47.5 1.1 2.8 39.8 1.0 2.3 42.6', 'Glenn Robinson', 'ATL 30 1.2 2.3 51.9 0.9 2.2 40.6 2.0 4.4 45.0 2.2 4.8 45.9 0.9 2.3 38.5 0.7 2.1 32.2', 'Gordan Giricek', 'ORL 26 1.6 2.6 60.5 0.5 1.1 48.1 0.4 1.0 37.2 0.6 1.5 37.2 1.2 3.2 37.8 0.4 1.2 33.3', 'Grant Hill', 'ORL 30 2.6 4.0 65.2 0.6 1.1 51.6 0.7 2.0 36.4 1.3 3.4 38.8 0.1 0.2 28.6 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Grant Long', 'BOS 37 0.2 0.4 56.3 0.1 0.1 40.0 0.0 0.2 16.7 0.3 0.7 37.9 0.1 0.3 30.8 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Greg Buckner', 'PHI 26 1.4 2.2 63.8 0.3 0.7 42.9 0.1 0.6 25.0 0.4 1.1 37.8 0.2 0.6 29.3 0.1 0.2 40.0', 'Greg Foster', 'TOR 34 0.4 0.8 45.8 0.2 0.5 40.0 0.3 0.7 50.0 0.6 1.8 31.4 0.1 0.4 30.0 0.0 0.1 50.0', 'Greg Ostertag', 'UTA 30 1.7 2.8 60.0 0.1 0.5 25.0 0.1 0.4 34.4 0.1 0.3 45.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Guy Rucker', 'GSW 25 0.0 0.0 0.0 - - - 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 - - - 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Hedo Turkoglu', 'SAC 24 0.7 1.3 53.4 0.2 0.6 34.1 0.2 0.4 50.0 0.6 1.4 41.1 0.6 1.7 36.7 0.2 0.5 37.9', 'Horace Grant', 'ORL 37 0.4 0.6 66.7 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.4 100 1.4 2.8 50.0 0.4 1.0 40.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Howard Eisley', 'NYK 30 0.7 1.3 53.8 0.1 0.3 47.8 0.1 0.4 34.5 0.4 1.0 36.6 1.3 3.0 43.1 0.6 1.7 36.4', 'Hubert Davis', 'DET 33 0.1 0.2 57.1 0.0 0.0 100 0.0 0.1 50.0 0.3 0.6 40.0 0.2 0.5 31.6 0.3 0.7 37.5', 'Igor Rakocevic', 'MIN 25 0.2 0.4 52.9 0.1 0.1 66.7 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.1 0.5 23.5 0.1 0.4 18.2 0.1 0.2 60.0', 'Ira Newble', 'ATL 28 1.7 2.6 64.4 0.1 0.3 38.1 0.2 0.6 43.9 0.6 1.6 40.0 0.4 1.2 38.1 0.1 0.2 33.3', 'J.R. Bremer', 'BOS 22 0.5 1.4 36.7 0.1 0.2 50.0 0.1 0.2 33.3 0.3 0.8 42.2 1.0 2.8 37.4 0.8 2.2 34.9', 'Jacque Vaughn', 'ORL 28 1.0 2.0 50.9 0.1 0.1 50.0 0.2 0.4 40.0 0.7 1.6 43.4 0.3 0.9 36.5 0.0 0.1 28.6', 'Jahidi White', 'WAS 27 1.4 2.9 50.0 0.1 0.4 33.3 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Jake Tsakalidis', 'PHX 24 1.2 2.5 48.8 0.4 1.1 36.4 0.1 0.4 36.4 0.1 0.2 57.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Jake Voskuhl', 'PHX 25 1.2 1.8 66.1 0.1 0.3 40.0 0.1 0.2 30.8 0.0 0.2 20.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Jalen Rose', 'CHI 30 1.4 2.9 48.3 0.8 1.9 43.1 1.3 3.1 41.7 2.2 5.7 39.3 1.3 3.6 36.4 0.8 2.0 37.6', 'Jamaal Magloire', 'NOH 25 2.8 4.8 57.6 0.6 1.7 36.2 0.3 0.8 31.8 0.1 0.3 19.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0', 'Jamaal Tinsley',]............

FYI using `split('\n')` won't help because the name of the players are separated by `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

That data is coming from [a xhr](https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayershotlocations?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&DistanceRange=5ft+Range&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2002-03&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=). So you would just get that with Requests and `json.loads` it.